# How do we find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}(1 - \sum_{k=1}^n 1/(n + \sqrt{k}))$?

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}\left(1 - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n + \sqrt{k}}\right)$$

Guys, please help to solve the limit.
I have try transfer it to integrate problem, but it works not good. My friends try to make the sum $f(n)$, it works but I don't know whether it done. I put it to python procedure getting the answer $2/3$. But I don't have specific math procedure. Thanks for help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! As it stands, your question is likely to be down-voted and/or closed. I've addressed some immediate problems: I've removed the picture and formatted your question with LaTeX instead, and I've given the post a more informative title. What we need from you is your own attempts to solve this problem. What have you tried? Did it get you anything promising? What kinds of tools do you have at your disposal for this kind of question? For example, expanding sums like this can sometimes reduce to Riemann sums; are you familiar with them? Any information you can provide is good.

Comment: I have try transfer it to integrate problem, but it works not good. My friends try to make the sum f(n),it works but I don’t know whether it done. I put it to python procedure getting the answer “2/3”. If you want to communicate deeply. You could send me email at colorowwang@gmail.com. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's excellent! I would advise putting that into the body of the question (your attempts, not your email) to stop more people voting to close it (it's at 4 out of 5 close votes now). Even if your question is closed, editing it will nominate it to be re-opened.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited it.

Answer (score 7):

$$A_n:=\sqrt{n}\left(1-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+\sqrt{k}}\right)=\sqrt{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+\sqrt{k}}\right)=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{k/n}}{1+\sqrt{k}/n}.$$

Since $1\leqslant 1+\sqrt{k}/n\leqslant 1+1/\sqrt{n}$, we get $$\frac{B_n}{1+1/\sqrt{n}}\leqslant A_n\leqslant B_n,\qquad B_n:=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k/n}.$$

Hence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}B_n$. Now $B_n$ is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1\sqrt{x}\,dx=2/3$.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a harmonic series sorry

Comment: That's perfect，Thanks very much.